# In Google Analytics, how to filter an entire ISP but allow specific IP addresses?

Tags: google-analytics

One of our clients wants to exclude any traffic from Amazon from logging into their Google Analytics. We need to be able to allow all traffic from 2 specific Amazon IP's though.

So is it possible to setup a rule sort of like "exclude all except..." in Filters? Or would we just setup one Exclude rule excluding ISP = Amazon and a second rule including the 2 Amazon IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish what you're asking.

In your proposed solution:

- Exclude Amazon ISP <- if the hit matched the Amazon ISP, it will be thrown out here.
- Include 2 Amazon IP <- this would never get evaluated for that hit.

If you do it the other way around:

- Include 2 Amazon IP <- this would be true, move to the next evaluation.
- Exclude Amazon ISP <- the hit would match here and it will be thrown out.

You CAN find all the IPs of the Amazon servers and exclude it all except the two you want to keep, otherwise you'll need to find another way to filter.

Comment: That's pretty much what we figured, we're gonna experiment nonetheless but wondered if anyone had encountered this before. Thx

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the reason behind wanting to filter this way? Maybe I can help you to come up with a solution.

Comment: Client wants to filter all Amazon traffic but allow our software to be able to send tracking events via http request in our backend. We run on Amazon services so currently the tracking requests we send to Google are blocked.

Comment: The ISP data that's available as a dimension, I think if you use UTM parameters for the traffic that your services are sending, then you can create a segment to "filter" that out. Your segment will be something like "exclude sessions where ISP = Amazon & source != Jared"

Comment: Ahh great thinking, that could very well work for us. I'll give it a go tomorrow and see what happens.